# AWS CLI Script to add security groups

Tags: bash, shell, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I've a script that I'm using to run `authorize-security-group-ingress` AWS CLI command.

```
IP = 10.10.10.10
CIDR = 32
Variable = sudo aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id sg-xxxxxx --ip-permissions FromPort=10,ToPort=23,IpProtocol=tcp,IpRanges='[{CidrIp=$((IP / 32))}]'
$Variable
```

But I get an error `CIDR block $((IP / 32)) is malformed`. I tried changing the `$((IP / 32))` block to `$IP/32` , `($(IP) / $(CIDR))` but I still seem to get the same error. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? The main issue is converting to a valid IP CIDR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do as Siddarth mentioned. Or, fix your query. The issue with your code is that you are using a single-quote (') instead of double-quotes (") for IpRanges. As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash) SO question, Single quotes won't interpolate anything, but double quotes will.

Once you replace it, your script will fail again because `$((...))` is an arithmetic expansion. Remove the `(())` in your script and it should work fine.

Final solution:

```
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id sg-xxxxxx --ip-permissions FromPort=10,ToPort=23,IpProtocol=tcp,IpRanges="[{CidrIp=$IP/$CIDR}]"
```

Comment: Tried this but it gives me a similar error. `sudo aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id sg-xxxx --ip-permissions FromPort=10,ToPort=23,IpProtocol=tcp,IpRanges="[{CidrIp=$IP/$CIDR}]"` `CIDR block / is malformed`

Comment: Can you share the value of IP and CIDR variables?

Comment: It actually worked by using your way and by correcting the way I declare the variable. It should be `IP=10.10.10.10` not `IP = 10.10.10.10` and the same with `CIDR`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it like this

```
'[{"IpProtocol":"tcp","IpRanges": [{"CidrIp": "10.10.10.10/32"}]}]'
```

Replacing your line of code with this worked for me.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that.. That worked for me too.. I'm trying to get an IP from another file, so temporarily I hard coded it as IP.